# How to check if a html control exists?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I check if an HTML control exists?

This is my code:

```
var id = ...
if(document.getElementById(id)!=null)
{
   //do something
}
```

if the html control is radio doesn't work.

How is this done?

Comment: It definitely does work if there's an "id" value on the radio button, or any other element type. Note that your "id" values must be unique on the page - no two elements can share a single "id" value, in other words.

Comment: Can you give an example of the radio input that's not working with this code, and let us know which browser you're using?  It should be working.

Comment: I'm using IE 7.
<input type="radio" id="my_radio_id" name="my_radio_id"> My Radio Button</input>
<input type="radio" id="my_radio_id" name="my_radio_id"> My Radio Button2</input>...

Comment: As Pointy says you can't have multiple elements with the same id. You'll need to rename one (though keep the name identical to ensure that you keep the radio buttons grouped).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function validate(ValFrm) {
  var len = ValFrm.elements.length;

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {

    if (ValFrm.elements[i].required == "Yes") {
      if (ValFrm.elements[i].value == "") {
        alert('The ' + ValFrm.elements[i].title + ' is required to contain data.');
        ValFrm.elements[i].focus();
        return false;
      }
    }

    if (ValFrm.elements[i].type == "radio") {
      if (!ValFrm.app[0].checked && !ValFrm.app[1].checked) {
        alert('Please accept or deny.');
        return false;
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: .. can you format the code by selecting all the code and clicking the little button with the 1s and 0s on it?

Comment: You can use the `101010` button on the toolbar to correctly format your code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i noticed Steve already edited it before me :)

Answer (score 9):

Further to your comments above, you should use a unique `id` for each radio button, but you can use the same `name` for your radio group. Consider the following example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
   <title>Testing document.getElementById()</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
   <input type="radio" id="my_radio_1_id" name="my_radios"> My Radio Button 1
   <input type="radio" id="my_radio_2_id" name="my_radios"> My Radio Button 2

   <script type="text/javascript"> 
     if (document.getElementById('my_radio_1_id')) {
       alert('It Exists');
     }
   </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

It will alert `'It Exists'` as expected.